# Defining `Reads` for JSON Set Type

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-json

How can I create a `play.api.libs.Reads` for my `People` case class?

```
scala> type Id = Long
defined type alias Id

scala> case class People(names: Set[Id])
defined class People

scala>   implicit val PeopleReads: Reads[People] = (
     |     (__ \ "names").read[Set[Id]])(People)
<console>:21: error: overloaded method value read with alternatives:
  (t: Set[Id])play.api.libs.json.Reads[Set[Id]] <and>
  (implicit r: play.api.libs.json.Reads[Set[Id]])play.api.libs.json.Reads[Set[Id]]
 cannot be applied to (People.type)
           (__ \ "names").read[Set[Id]])(People)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(...)(People)` syntax is designed for when you've built up a list of arguments (well, technically it's a `Builder`, not a list) with `and` and want to lift the `People` constructor into the applicative functor for `Reads` so that you can apply it to those arguments.

For example, if your `People` type looked like this:

```
case class People(names: Set[Id], home: String)
```

You could write:

```
implicit val PeopleReads: Reads[People] = (
  (__ \ "names").read[Set[Id]] and
  (__ \ "home").read[String]
)(People)
```

In your case, though, the constructor for `People` has a single argument, and you haven't used `and`, so you don't have a `Builder[Reads[Set[Id] ~ String]`, you've just got a plain old `Reads[Set[Id]]`.

This is nice, because it means you don't need the weird applicative functor syntax—all you need is `map`:

```
implicit val PeopleReads = (__ \ "names").read[Set[Id]].map(People)
```

And you're done.

Comment: Is `__` the same as `JsPath`? If so, is `__` preferred? If so, why?

Comment: Yep, it's just an alias, and it's designed to provide a specific kind of DSL. It's not the sort of thing I'm usually into, personally, but I happen to like the syntax well enough in this case. I don't think there's any "preferred" to it beyond that—you can take it or leave it.

Comment: Could you please say more as to `...read[Set[Id]].map(People)`? What is the signature of the `People` function? I know `People` is a case class, but I understand map: `M[A].map(A => B):M[B]`

Comment: It's just shorthand for `People.apply`, or `(ids: Set[Id]) => People(ids)`.

Comment: Thanks, Travis. Also, could you please tell me how to write `Writes` for people? I tried `implicit val PeopleWrites: Writes[People] = (JsPath \ "names").write[Set[Int]].map(unlift(x => Some((x.names)))`, but failed.

Comment: It might be better to ask that as a new question?

Comment: Sure. Sorry, that was rude of me. Let me open a new one.

Comment: Not rude—any answer's just more likely to be useful to more people if it's not in this comment thread.

Comment: Thanks - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714825/create-writes-and-format-of-case-class.