# Create Writes and Format of Case Class

Tags: json, scala, playframework

For this case class:

`case class People(names: Set[Int])`

[Travis Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334519/travis-brown) explained how to create `PeopleReads: Reads[People]` at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461590/defining-reads-for-json-set-type/21461939?noredirect=1#comment32835638_21461939.):

```
implicit val PeopleReads = 
       (__ \ "names").read[Set[Id]].map(People)
```

But, I'm trying to implement `PeopleWrites: Writes[People]`:

```
 implicit val PeopleWrites: Writes[People] = 
    (JsPath \  "names").write[Set[Int]].map(unlift(x => Some((x.names)))
```

with the following compile-time error:

```
scala> People( Set(1,2,3))
res5: People = People(Set(1, 2, 3))

scala>  implicit val PeopleWrites: Writes[People] = 
      (JsPath \  "names").write[Set[Int]].map(unlift(x => Some((x.names))))
<console>:21: error: value map is not a member of 
                play.api.libs.json.OWrites[Set[Int]]
              implicit val PeopleWrites: Writes[People] = 
                (JsPath \  "names").write[Set[Int]].
                                      map(unlift(x => Some((x.names)))
```

How can I resolve this error?

Also, how can I write `Format[People]` where I get/define both `Reads` and `Writes`:

`val peopleFormat: Format[People] = ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question! The reason you can't use `map` is because `Writes` isn't a functor.

You can think of `Writes[A]` as something kind of like `A => JsValue`. But suppose I've got a `A => JsValue` and a `A => B`. Try to come up with some way of composing those functions to get a `B => JsValue`—it's just not possible.

`Reads[A]`, on the other hand, is kind of like `JsValue => A`, and is a functor—it has a `map` method that takes a `A => B`, composes it with the `Reads[A]` / `JsValue => A`, and returns a `Reads[B]` / `JsValue => B`.

`Writes` is, however, a *contravariant* functor, and luckily enough [Play knows that](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.functional.ContravariantFunctorOps). When `F` is a contravariant functor, `F[A]` has a method `contramap[B](f: B => A)` instead of the usual `map[B](f: A => B)`. So you can just write this:

```
case class People(names: Set[Int])

import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit val PeopleWrites: Writes[People] =
  (__ \ 'names).write[Set[Int]].contramap(_.names)
```

Here `(__ \ 'names).write[Set[Int]]` is a `Writes[Set[Int]]` and `(_.names)` is a function `People => Set[Int]`. Combining them with `contramap` gives us a `Writes[People]`.

Comment: Thanks, Travis. Could you please show how to write, if possible, `Writes[People]` using `unlift`? Also, what would `Format[People]` look like? Thanks again.

Comment: Updated with some additional information about the argument to `contramap`. Also, you don't need `unlift` when you're not dealing with something like a case class's `unapply`, and you've already got a `Format[People]` once you've got implicit `Reads` and `Writes` instances in scope, thanks to the implicit `Format.GenericFormat`.

Comment: So `Writes[Set[Int]].contramap(f)` where `f` has signature: `Set[Int] => People`. `_.names` expands to `(x => x.names)`. And `contra` in contra`map` means that, for the `function: B => A`, we're passing in `Person => Set[Int]`, but the reverse actually occurs - `Set[Int] => Person`?

Comment: Not exactly. Think of `Reads` and `Writes` as pipes between `A` and `JsValue`. `contramap` puts a `B => A` _in front_ of the `Writes` pipe. `map` puts a `A => B` _after_ the `Reads` pipe.