# Why can't I serialize Map[String,Any] to JSON?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I can't seem to find a proper way to serialize my Map to a JSON object, when it has different types for the value, i.e.:

```
var user: Map[String, Any] = Map("name" -> "1", "id" -> 1)
val json: JsValue = Json.obj(
  "user" -> user
)
```

produces:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Map[String,Any]
 required: play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper
```

Or, if I use instead `Map[String,AnyVal]`, it produces:

```
the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyVal
```

But if I use either `Map[String,Number]` or `Map[String,String]` it works.

What am I missing, is there some wrapper I can call to safely use both numbers and integers on my JSON.obj() call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your code snippet you will need to do the following:

```
var user = Map("name" -> "1", "id" -> 1)
var json: JsValue = Json.obj(
    "user" -> Json.toJson(user)
)
```

The next problem that will arise is that Play cannot find an implicit `writes` for type `Map[String, Any]`.

I'd recommend writing your own `Writes` for the object you're trying to serialize. Maybe something like the below:

```
case class User(props: Map[String, Any])

implicit val writes: Writes[User] = new Writes[User]{
  override def writes(o: User): JsValue = {
    val propsJs = JsObject(
      o.props.map{kvp =>
        kvp._1 -> (kvp._2 match {
          case x: String => JsString(x)
          case x: Int => JsNumber(x)
          case _ => JsNull // Do whatever you want here.
        })
      }
    )
    JsObject(Map("user" -> propsJs))
  }
}
```

With a test:

```
val u1 = User(Map("name" -> "1", "id" -> 1))

val js = Json.toJson(u1)

out: js: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"user":{"name":"1","id":1}}
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the comment, it may be advantageous (depending on your use case) to do the following:

```
case class User(name: String, id: Int)

implicit val writes = Json.writes[User]
```

This is a more readable and better solidifies the definition of a `User`. It may be possible that you cannot do this however if you can I (and others) would suggest it.

Comment: I believe that using `case class User(props: Map[String, Any])` is confusing. Why not specify the actual member fields of `User` as `String`, `Int`, etc, and then define a `Writes[User]` per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714825/create-writes-and-format-of-case-class/?

Comment: @KevinMeredith I agree with you. OP asked to serialize Map[String, Any]. I'll update with aforementioned suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I recommend reading this helpful explanation from Travis Brown - https://github.com/travisbrown/circe/issues/216#issuecomment-191730128.