# Defining Writes[...] for a Case Class w/ Tuple

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Given this range class:

`case class Range(things: (String, String))`

I tried to implement `Writes[Range]` from the Play Json [docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1-RC2/ScalaJsonCombinators) example on `Creature`.

```
implicit val rangeWrites: Writes[Range] =
  (JsPath \ "things").write(
    (JsPath \ "string").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "string").write[String]
      tupled
  )(unlift(Range.unapply))
```

However, I got:

```
[error] JsonTest.scala 19 could not find implicit value for 
        parameter app: play.api.libs.functional.
                                 Applicative[play.api.libs.json.OWrites]
[error]       (JsPath \ "items").write(
```

How can I properly fill in the `(JsPath \ "items").write(`? In the docs' example, there doesn't appear to be any type required.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is very similar to the one that shows up in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21461939/334519): you can't use the applicative syntax on a plain old `Writes` (or `OWrites`)—you need a `Builder`.

The solution is also similar here, but instead of `map` you need `contramap`, since `Writes` is a contravariant functor, not a functor:

```
implicit val rangeWrites: Writes[Range] =
  (JsPath \ "things").write(
    (JsPath \ "string1").write[String] and
    (JsPath \ "string2").write[String]
      tupled
  ).contramap(unlift(Range.unapply))
```

Also note that I've changed the keys to `string1` and `string2`—if you use the same key you're not going to get what you expect.

Comment: thanks, Travis. Do you find svenslaggare's answer sufficient too?

Comment: It's fine—I prefer the more compositional functional style, but that's largely just taste. If I were writing this in my own code I'd use `contramap` but I'd be explicit in order to avoid the `unlift`.

Comment: `my own code I'd use contramap but I'd be explicit in order to avoid the unlift` - could you please say more?

Comment: `contramap` takes a function that takes a `Range` and returns a `(String, String)`. You can write that as `unlift(Range.unapply)`, or you can write it as `_.things`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to implement the Writes trait directly, which gives you better control how the object is converted into JSON.

Example:

```
    implicit object RangeWrites extends Writes[Range] {
    def writes(value: Range): JsValue = {
        Json.obj("things" -> Json.arr(value.things._1, value.things._2))
    }
}
```

Which gives the following JSON: `{"things":["hello","all"]}` for the object: `Range(("hello", "all"))`